# Javascript match string against string in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

I have a set of input fields, each with the class "smarty_address_check"

```
<input type="text" class="smarty_address_check" value="this is a new value" />
<input type="text" class="smarty_address_check" value="this value has been unchanged" />
etc
```

What I need to do is

- for each input field value
- compare that value to each of the values in the array (array is called smarty_address_check)
- if it matches, do something.

The values in the array are the **original default/example values of the input fields**, and if the user hasn't changed them I want to act on that.

```
var exampleAddressPresent = false;
    for (var i = 0; i<smarty_address_check.length; i++) {
        $('.smarty_address_check').each(function() { //For each of inputs
            if (smarty_address_check[i].match($(this).val())) { //if match against array
                var exampleAddressPresent = true; //Example address present
                console.log($(this).attr("id")); //store id of unchanged input

            }
        });
    }
```

I get the feeling this is bad programming logic, not to mention I can't work out why it isn't working properly. All I basically want to do is compare one string against another. Does anybody know of a better way to approach this?

Comment: Remove your second "var" keyword on exampleAddressPresent.
Because it redefines it locally, and you won't be able to use it globally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `match()` to compare two strings. There is the common `===` compare operator

```
if(smarty_address_check[i] === $(this).val()) {
```

EDIT: If the index of the array matches the index/position of the input, you can avoid the outer loop by using the same index

```
$('.smarty_address_check').each(function(index) { //For each of inputs
    if (smarty_address_check[index] === $(this).val()) { //if match against array
        exampleAddressPresent = true; //Example address present
        console.log($(this).attr("id")); //store id of unchanged input
    }
});
```

Comment: Yep saw it ! And remove the var cause this var is already defined globally !

Comment: `index` is an optional parameter of the `.each()` method holding the index of the current element inside the jQuery object

Answer (score 0):

If the `array` you are checking against is `an Array of strings`, a possible solution would be :

### Convert the values in the Array to one single string:

```
var myArray = ['apples', 'mangoes', 'bananas'] // example Array of strings
var string = myArray.join(':'); // we'll get "apples:mangoes:bananas"
```

### Next, we can check if our value is on that string

```
var myValue = 'apples' // example input value
if(string.indexOf(myValue) !== -1) 
  // do something (i.e. myValue matches with one of the values on myArray)
```

Good Luck